# NFS performs ways worse than SSHFS, how can I debug?

Tags: nfs, performance-tuning

Situation: zfs server over 10GbE p2p at `192.168.201.1` running omnios, debian client at `192.168.201.2`. The nfs performs fairly well on big files but horribly slow on small ones. For instance, `cp -r /etc /mnt/nfs_mountpoint` takes 8 minutes while `cp -r /etc /mnt/sshfs_mountpoint` to the same machine takes 40 seconds.

I have experimented quite a lot with nfs mount parameters. Currently, the mount looks like this:

```
zfs:/z2pool/fs on /mnt/shared/fs type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.201.1,mountvers=3,mountport=61082,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.201.1)
```

I've been stuck here for weeks now. I won't downvote anything, hence trial n error suggestions are welcome.

Update: I have tried both async and sync with no or little difference.

Comment: To my mind the biggest difference is to do with locking (and cache-coherency).

Comment: The command `nfsiostat` will also have some useful counters. If you do a packet capture, you can use `tshark` to start looking at locking performance (you can see a hint of this technique at this bit-rotten old site of mine which I need to restore one day : https://web.archive.org/web/20120630133918/http://humbledown.org/index.xhtml)

Comment: A difference (just guessing) might be in sshfs being asynchronous by default, while nfs being synchronous. Another thing worth trying is `proto=udp`. On lossless networks, such as your p2p 10GbE, it could actually work better.

Answer (score 0):

This page mentions performance optimising, and mentions things like sync versus async options for NFS.

http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s05.html

Comment: I should have mentioned I've already tried mostly all options there is that could possibly affect the performance, including async vs sync. Updated original post.